# Capitalize words in a string

Tags: sql, oracle

I've used INITCAP to capitalize words in a string, but I've run into a small issue:

```
select initcap(q'[JOE'S CARD 'N' CANDY]') from dual;
```

It returns "*Joe'S Card 'N' Candy*", but I wonder if there is another way to capitalize the words so it will look like this "*Joe's Card 'N' Candy*" (notice the **s** is in lowercase)

Comment: As there are no other parameters for initcap, I guess your best option is to replace '''S ' with '''s '.

Comment: Ok, found some evidence that this problem was first noticed almost 10 years ago. Discussed in Oracle community forum: https://community.oracle.com/thread/625330

Comment: This will be tricky because unfortunately `regexp_replace` does not provide a way to manipulate the case of a backreference (as you can in Vim with `\L&` for example), and you can't necessarily replace all `'S` with `'s` in case the name is something like `Walker 'Sugar Ray' Smith`.

Comment: @EdgarsT.: thx. The discussion "Use REGEXP_REPLACE as advanced initcap function?" from Oracle community forum is "pure gold"!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adapted from [this answer](https://community.oracle.com/message/2381108#2381108) to use a single simpler regular expression to parse each word:

```
WITH names ( name ) AS (
  SELECT 'FIRSTNAME O''MALLEY'     FROM DUAL UNION
  SELECT 'FIRST''NAME  TEH''TE'    FROM DUAL UNION
  SELECT 'FORMAT ME BYGGER''N'     FROM DUAL UNION
  SELECT 'OLD MCDONALD'            FROM DUAL UNION
  SELECT 'EVEN OL''DER MACDONALD'  FROM DUAL UNION
  SELECT q'[JOE'S CARD 'N' CANDY]' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT name,
       formatted_name
FROM   names
MODEL
PARTITION BY (ROWNUM rn)
DIMENSION BY (0 dim)
MEASURES(name, CAST('' AS VARCHAR2(255)) word, CAST('' AS VARCHAR(255)) formatted_name)
RULES ITERATE(99) UNTIL (word[0] IS NULL)
(
    word[0] = REGEXP_SUBSTR(name[0], '[^ ]+( *|$)', 1, ITERATION_NUMBER + 1),
    formatted_name[0] = formatted_name[0]
      -- Capitalise names starting with ', *', MC and MAC:
      || INITCAP(REGEXP_SUBSTR( word[0], '^([^'']?''|ma?c)?(.)(.*)$', 1, 1, 'i', 1 ) )
      -- Capitalise the next letter of the word
      || UPPER(  REGEXP_SUBSTR( word[0], '^([^'']?''|ma?c)?(.)(.*)$', 1, 1, 'i', 2 ) )
      -- Lower case the rest of the word
      || LOWER(  REGEXP_SUBSTR( word[0], '^([^'']?''|ma?c)?(.)(.*)$', 1, 1, 'i', 3 ) )
);
```

**Output**:

```
NAME                    FORMATTED_NAME
----------------------- ----------------------
EVEN OL'DER MACDONALD   Even Ol'der MacDonald
OLD MCDONALD            Old McDonald
FIRST'NAME  TEH'TE      First'name  Teh'te
FORMAT ME BYGGER'N      Format Me Bygger'n
JOE'S CARD 'N' CANDY    Joe's Card 'N' Candy
FIRSTNAME O'MALLEY      Firstname O'Malley
```

Answer (score 3):

In your place I would create a custom PL/SQL procedure of the kind:

```
create or replace function initcap_cust(p_input varchar2)
return varchar2
as
  l_input                    varchar2(4000) := lower(p_input);
  l_capitalize_first_letter  boolean := true;
  l_output                   varchar2(4000) := null;
  l_curr_char                char(1);
begin
  -- here we iterate over the lowercased string characters
  for i in 1..length(l_input) loop
    l_curr_char := substr(l_input, i, 1);
    -- if we find a space - OK, next alphabet letter should be capitalized
    -- you can add here more delimiters, e.g.: l_curr_char in (' ', ',', etc) 
    if l_curr_char = ' ' then
      l_capitalize_first_letter := true;
    end if;
    -- makes O'Sullivan look this way
    if regexp_like(l_output, '(^| )O''$') then
      l_capitalize_first_letter := true;
    end if;
    -- found the first letter after delimiter - OK, capitalize 
    if l_capitalize_first_letter and (l_curr_char between 'a' and 'z') then
      l_curr_char := upper(l_curr_char);
      l_capitalize_first_letter := false;
    end if;
    -- build the output string
    l_output := l_output || l_curr_char;
  end loop;

  return l_output;
end;
```

It works in your case and similar ones. Also it can be customized depending on your needs without dealing with complex queries built using the only functions provided by Oracle out of the box.

**N.B.** Also there is an option to create equivalent *java stored procedure*, on the  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48186455/capitalize-words-in-a-string#comment83353658_48186455) provided by Edgars T. there is an [example](https://community.oracle.com/message/2381270#2381270).

Comment: Added support for O'Sullivan, easy and readable.  
Again, each time you struggle with a situation **"some letter is uppercased or not"**, you should decide yourself if it is correct (e.g. is 'Machine' an Irish surname?). In my opinion, stored procedure fits better as gives more flexibility and has more chances to be understood many years later.